# Organizing services/daemons with systems: running 100+ daemons, grouped by 3

Tags: systemd

I'm new to `systemd`.

I have a machine that needs to run a substantial number of daemons. There are three types of daemons, call them **daemon-A**, **daemon-B**, **daemon-C**.

These daemons always run in "groups" of 3, with a configuration specific to those 3.

Occasionally, it would be necessary to restart or stop a whole group.

What's the best way to explain this to `systemd`?

My current knowledge would make me simply create a new `.service` file for every **daemon-A**, **daemon-B**, **daemon-C**, for every configuration. I'm slightly lost when it comes to cgroups and slices, in that I sort of understand what they do, but a practical use case is still slightly beyond me.

I would need to be able to check on a particular group in a simple way.

Is this the way to go? Is there anything wrong with having such a big number of `systemd`-managed services?

Answer (score 2):

systemd actually has [several unit configuration options](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) which you can use to express the dependencies between these services.

In particular you will want to look at `Requires=`, `Before=`, `After=`, `BindsTo=` and `PartOf=`, all of which specify different ways in which a unit may be started or stopped in relation to other units. There are several other less commonly used ones, so read through the documentation carefully in case your daemons can use them.

(Because you didn't say exactly what the dependencies between your services are, I can't recommend which option you should use.)

---

Also, systemd can have [instanced units](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html), which start the same service but with a different configuration. An instanced unit has a name ending with `@`, and the instance is the name following the `@`. In the unit file, `%I` and `%i` are replaced with the instance name, which you can use to load specific configuration files. For example, in an instanced unit `foo@.service`, you might specify:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foo --daemon --config=/etc/foo/%i.conf
```

Then, to enable the `foo` service in a `bar` instance, you would say:

```
systemctl enable foo@bar
```

Which will cause the foo service to start with /etc/foo/bar.conf.

---

Note also that you can specify instances in the requirements as well. For instance, if `a@.service` requires `b@.service` of the same instance name, you can say in `a@.service`:

```
Requires=b@%i.service
```

Comment: I really like the instanced units, they seem near-perfect in this case. As to the dependencies between the 3 daemons, there are none. It's just that all need to be run at once. On the topic of starting and stopping groups: is there a way to say "stop/start/restart all services of the X instance" (other than scripting it)?

Comment: `Requires=` will handle that. If you start one service containing that, it will also start any named services simultaneously. You can list it in all three, and then start or stop _any_ of them to get all three started or stopped.

Comment: Got it. I created an instanced service file daemon-A@.service and I'm using %i inside both Description= and ExecStart=, but it doesn't seem to be replaced in ExecStart=. The service fails with a no such file error, and the report clearly shows the unreplaced %i in the start command. Description= is replaced fine. Did I miss anything, or is this some weirdness I just bumped into and I'm on my own?

Comment: Did you give the instance a name? e.g. `systemctl enable daemon-A@whatever`

Comment: No, I'm not enabling the service. I'm trying `systemctl start daemon-A@something.service`. If I do `status`, I can see the %I inside `Description=` was replaced with "something", but the `ExecStart=` command failed because it couldn't find /opt/%I/daemon (example).

Comment: I've just noticed this pattern: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/something %I` **OKAY**, `ExecStart=/usr/bin/something/%I` **NOT OKAY**. Seems like adding it to a path isn't working... investigating further.

Comment: Got it: `Note that the first argument of the command line (i.e. the program to execute) may not include specifiers.` Source: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html